# How to delete a line up to a certain snapping point (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, toolbox

Is there a way/tool to delete lines up to a certain snapping point, so that once I've drawn a line I don't have to manually delete each vertex until I reach the desired point or completely delete the line and redraw it?

I'm working on QGIS 3.22.6.

Comment: Please provide screenshots showing what you're intending to do.

Comment: Indeed: your question is unclear, I don't understand what you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming by snapping point you mean a vertex, this is possible using the split feature tool.

[image]

With the tool activated select the desired vertex, split the feature into two parts and delete one of the two parts afterwards.

Don't forget to turn snapping on.